# Options for aside that can be after main content in mobile views, top right for tablet/desktop

Tags: html, css, css-float, responsive-design

Working on a responsive design and I'm curious what my options are for positioning an aside that appears on the top right of the content area in widescreen views but AFTER the main content in mobile browsers.

e.g.

```
Here's the article. [list of winners]
Article text can wrap around the aside.
Article text can wrap around the aside.
```

In html5 I know I could use the following HTML:

```
<div class="main">
<article>Here's the article</article>
<aside>List of winners</aside>
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:768px) {
.main article {
    float:left;
    width:57%;
}
.main aside {
    float:right;
    width:28%;
}
}
```

That would allow me to have the aside next to the article in widescreen and below for mobiles. But the article text would not be wrapped around the bottom of the aside and would be kept at the 57% width for the full length of the page, even after the aside was finished.

Is there any way to achieve what I'm looking for or would the solution be too kludgy?

Thanks.

Comment: I know this is ugly, but would you mind duplicating the `<aside>`?

Comment: You could use CSS Flexbox. It allows source order independence through the order property. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#order-property Depends on if you need to support IE9 and below or not though. If you're targeting Windows Phone 8 and not 7, it should be ok to use for mobile styles. Providing you use the old syntax as well for iOS and Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### If you don't mind involving JS:

http://jsfiddle.net/77NwN/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <aside class="float">List of winners</aside>
    <article>
        <p>Here's the article</p>
        <p>Article text that can wrap around &lt;aside&gt;</p>
        <p>Article text that can wrap around &lt;aside&gt;</p>
    </article>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
@media {
    .main aside.float {
        display:none;
    }
}
@media (min-width:350px) {
    .main aside.under {
        display:none;
    }
    .main aside.float {
        display:initial;
        float:right;
        width:28%;
    }
}
```

JS:

```
window.onload=function(){
    var aside=document.querySelector("div.main aside.float");
    aside=aside.cloneNode(true);
    aside.className="under";
    document.querySelector("div.main").appendChild(aside);
};
```

---

#### If you don't mind using `flexbox`:

(Inspired by @dstorey)

**Warning**: Only tested on Chrome 26 desktop and Firefox 21 desktop. [Compatible table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) / [MDN guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

http://jsfiddle.net/77NwN/3/

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <aside>List of winners</aside>
    <article>
        <p>Here's the article</p>
        <p>Article text that can wrap around &lt;aside&gt;</p>
        <p>Article text that can wrap around &lt;aside&gt;</p>
    </article>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
@media {
    .main aside {
        float:right;
        width:28%;
    }
}
@media (max-width:350px) { /* notice I change min-width to max-width */
    .main {
        display:-webkit-flex;
        display:flex;
        -webkit-flex-direction:column;
        flex-direction:column;
    }
    .main article {
        -webkit-order:1;
        order:1;
    }
    .main aside {
        -webkit-order:2;
        order:2;
        float:initial;
        width:initial;
    }
}
```

No JS involved.

I'm not sure what the "old syntax" really is, as I didn't pay much attention on that topic when they're discussing it...

Comment: Thanks. I'll give these a try as soon as I have a few minutes this afternoon.

Comment: I tried both. Even though I'm using FF21, the Flexbox version didn't send the side to the bottom. The Javascript version worked like a charm. Is there _any_ way to copy the info into .under without it remaining hidden in .aside? Or is it not a big issue since the duplication only happens _after_ a mobile browser has downloaded it?

Comment: @Ian Yes I like the JS version too, it's more spool proof. It really isn't a big issue, as the list would not download twice (it's just a DOM clone _after_ page downloaded), so the only extra bandwidth is that JS snippet. It does heavied the rendering engine _a little bit_, but I think that would not be something you need to concern.